# Win32gui не работает в программе

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

Есть приложение Bluestacks и, когда оно ещё только загружается win32gui работает. Я могу узнать цвет пикселя, нажать кнопку, но после загрузки при попытке кликнуть куда либо ничего не происходит, а если попробовать узнать цвет пикселя, то скрипт закрывается. В другой программе все прекрасно работает. Может ли bluestacks блокировать python? Если да, то есть аналоги этого модуля?

```
    def click(hwndChild, x, y):
        lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)
        win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
        win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: скрипт закрывается без ошибок ? если есть ошибки то добавьте их полный текст в вопрос. если нету, то нажмите Win+R введите eventvwr.msc и посмотрите там в журнале приложений

Comment: Простите, сейчас решил сесть за пк и дождаться этой ошибки. В итоге ошибок нет и он может видеть цвет пикселей.  Но клики до сих пор не работают. Просто ничего не происходит. Я добавил функцию клика.

Comment: попробуйте делать клики вот этим https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/